# Make theme settings in Phonegap app persistent - with jQuery cookies

Tags: jquery, cordova, local-storage, persistent-storage, jquery-cookie

I've got an Phonegap app with different theme options. To make the theme selection persistent with each app start, I want to set a cookie with jQuery. But after each refresh in the browser (where I test), the standard theme is back.

Can u give me some hints?

### That's the **markup** at the beginning of my app:

```
<body>
  <div class="theme1">
   <div id="page1">
   (...) // app markup
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
  <script>HERE GOES MY SCRIPT</script>
</body>
```

There I set the standard theme.

### Now, what I do, is, when I click on another theme (#theme8, for instance) then this happens in **my script**:

```
    $('#theme8').bind('click', function () {
     if ($('body > div').hasClass('theme8')) {
      // go back to the home screen
   } else {
        $('body > div').removeClass();
        $('body > div').addClass("theme8");
       // go back to the homescreen
   }
     $.cookie('theme_eight', 'applied');
   });
```

### **That's my cookie:**

```
var theme_eight = $.cookie('theme_eight');
if (theme_eight == 'applied') { 
    $('body > div').removeClass();
    $('body > div').addClass("theme8");
};
```

**Same goes with the other 7 themes. So what is wrong with that? Why does my theme choice not persist? Is there a neater solution to accomplish that?**

Answer (score 0):

Rather then a cookie look at Localstorage. Its persistent and better then using cookies

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage

```
 function onDeviceReady() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
        var keyname = window.localStorage.key(i);
        // keyname is now equal to "key"
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem("key");
        // value is now equal to "value"
        window.localStorage.removeItem("key");
        window.localStorage.setItem("key2", "value2");
        window.localStorage.clear();
        // localStorage is now empty
    }
```